# Undefined property: Auth::$model [CodeIgniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter

I know this quention might seems duplicated, but i already tried those suggestions/advice but still couldn't solve this:

environment :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('email', 'session', 'database', 'form_validation');
```

controller :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('Auth_model', 'Auth');
}

private function _login()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $user = $this->model->Auth->getUser();
```

Model :

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function getUser()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        // var_dump($email);die;
        return $this->db->get_where('t_user', ['email' => $email])->row_array();
    }
}
```

I Still got this error :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Auth::$model
>
> Filename: controllers/Auth.php
>
> Line Number: 38

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
   $user = $this->model->Auth->getUser();
```

into

```
$user = $this->Auth->getUser();
```

Comment: i already load the model from constructor (i edit my answer) sorry for not mentioning before, and this still doesn;t work

Comment: thanks man, this works great :) ! but would you please tell me why i don't need to call the model-> first ?

Answer (score 0):

try this into the class you will use
Type `$ this-> library -> (" library you want ")`. I hope it helps.

Comment: i've already load the class/model from constructor and it still doesn't work